# Start row index from 1 instead of zero without creating additional column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I know that I can reset the indices like so

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

but this will start the index from `0`. I want to start it from `1`.  How do I do that without creating any extra columns and by keeping the index/reset_index functionality and options? I do *not* want to create a new dataframe, so `inplace=True` should still apply.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Just assign directly a new index array:

```
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
```

Or if the index is already 0 based, just:

```
df.index += 1
```

Example:

```
In [151]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[151]:
          a
0  0.443638
1  0.037882
2 -0.210275
3 -0.344092
4  0.997045
In [152]:

df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
df
Out[152]:
          a
1  0.443638
2  0.037882
3 -0.210275
4 -0.344092
5  0.997045
```

**TIMINGS**

For some reason I can't take timings on `reset_index` but the following are timings on a 100,000 row df:

```
In [160]:

%timeit df.index = df.index + 1
The slowest run took 6.45 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop


In [161]:

%timeit df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 154 µs per loop
```

So without the timing for `reset_index` I can't say definitively, however it looks like just adding 1 to each index value will be faster if the index is already `0` based

Comment: `np.arange(len(df)) + 1` is equivalent, right? That's more readable to me.

Answer (score 11):

You can also specify the start value using index range like below. RangeIndex is supported in pandas.

```
#df.index
```

default value is printed, (start=0,stop=lastelement, step=1)

You can specify any start value range like this:

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=600, step=1)
```

Refer: [pandas.RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html)

Answer (score 4):

For this, you can do the following(I created an example dataframe):

```
price_of_items = pd.DataFrame({
"Wired Keyboard":["$7","4.3","12000"],"Wireless Keyboard":["$13","4.6","14000"]
                             })
price_of_items.index += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to simply increment each index value by 1 (which changes the index in-place).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})
df.index += 1
```

Another is to assign a new range index, that starts from 1, using `set_axis()`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})
df = df.set_axis(range(1, len(df)+1))
```

In fact, since `set_axis()` assigns a new object to the index, i.e. resets the index, it can be used *instead of* `reset_index()`.

It is especially useful if you need to make the index to start from 1 in a pipeline (where assigning or incrementing index wouldn't work).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [4, 1, 2, 3]})
df = (
    df
    .reset_index()
    .set_axis(range(1, len(df)+1))
)
```

[image: result1]

or the dataframe shape needs to be modified in the pipeline (e.g. using `query()`), `pipe()` could be used.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [4, 1, 2, 3]})
df = (
    df
    .query('col > 2')
    .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(range(1, len(x)+1)))
)
```

[image: result2]