# Start index (under FIeld) from 1 with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to start the index from 1 undes the "Field" column

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(total_points, passing_percentage)),
                 columns =['Pts Measured', '% pass'])
df = df.rename_axis('Field').reset_index()
df["Comments"] = ""
df
```

Output:

```
  Field  Pts Measured   % pass  Comments
0   0       92909       90.66   
1   1       92830       91.85   
2   2      130714       99.99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question here: [In Python pandas, start row index from 1 instead of zero without creating additional column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249960/in-python-pandas-start-row-index-from-1-instead-of-zero-without-creating-additi)

For your question, it would be as simple as adding the following line:

```
df["Field"] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```