# How to reset the index of a Pandas dataframe starting from a user-defined value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to *reset* the index of a dataframe from a user-defined value, *e.g.* 42.

Let us consider a simple dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32249984/6440589) simply suggests shifting the dataframe's indices:

```
df.index = df.index + 42
```

This returns:

```
    a
42  1
43  2
44  3
45  4
46  5
```

But is it possible to use pandas' `reset_index` method to do the same?

The best solution that I found so far is to reset the index first and then shift the indices:

```
def reset_index_from_user_defined_value(df, starting_index = 42):
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df.index = df.index + starting_index
    return df
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way to do it

set index using an array that starts with the user-defined start value

```
start=42
df.set_index( np.arange(start, start+len(df)))
```

```
    a
42  1
43  2
44  3
45  4
46  5
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this elegant solution, @Naveed! `set_index` will do the trick!