# How to conitnue a consecutive row number in pyspark(AWS glue)

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue script using pyspark. I have to create a unique surrogate key. Ive been using row_number and monatically increasing, and it works on the first job but every time I upload new files and run the job again it starts the number back at 1. Any guidance on how I can keep the sequential continuing when new files are added? For more info I'm uploading to an Oracle Database.

Current table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Jon | 1 |
| doe | 2 |

Table after a upload

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Jon | 1 |
| doe | 2 |
| Jean | 1 |

What I want after a upload

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Jon | 1 |
| doe | 2 |
| Jean | 3 |

Comment: Unless there is any hidden context to the question (in which case you need to [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with an example of the code you are using) then the answer is to use a `SEQUENCE` or an `IDENTITY` column within the database (and not trying to manage this from your script).

Comment: That was an option but with that route I run into roadblocks of having to match the id to certain files to populate more tables.

Comment: See my previous comment regarding hidden context; you have not explained any of that in the question and if you do not explain why you should not do it a certain way (that is otherwise best-practice) then we will suggest doing it that way (and this is a duplicate question). If you don't think it is a duplicate question then [edit] the question to explain why.

Comment: this exactly my scenario right here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59399926/19095452