# How to numerate from id = 1 and name the first column as "Id"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

My code parses data from csv file, that is craeted in "correct" notation.

I have several tables as result, that were obtained by the columnnames of this csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

def parseColumnsByPandas(filePath):

    col_names = ["Car","MPG","Cylinders","Displacement","Horsepower","Weight","Acceleration","Model","Origin"]
    df = pd.read_csv(filePath,skiprows=1,names=col_names)
    
    for column_name, column_data in df.iteritems():
        un_df = sorted(column_data.unique())
        res_df = pd.DataFrame(un_df,columns = [f'{column_name}'])
        print(res_df)
        res_df.to_csv(f"D:\\out\\unique_{column_name}.csv")

filePath = r"D:/out/cars_norm.csv"
parseColumnsByPandas(filePath)
```

How could I get Id in the first column as a header and numeration, that begins from 1 not from zero?

Comment: Use `res_df.index += 1`

Comment: Yes, I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167930/start-index-at-1-for-pandas-dataframe
How to use, thanks!

Comment: but how to name header with "Id"?

Comment: If it is column use `res_df['col' ]+= 1`

Comment: This is column, but header there is not set. My output now still  without header in first cell.

Comment: I think I got it. Need `res_df.index += 1` and then `res_df = res_df.rename_axis('Id').reset_index()`

Comment: Now I have 3 columns and in first there is no header, I dont need this column. But in second and third - all correct.
Empty  Id  Origin
0          1     CAT

Comment: res_df = res_df.rename_axis('Id') - WORKS, thanks, jezrael!