# Convert csv to excel and and indexing from 1 (python)

Tags: python, excel, csv, indexing

```
import pandas as pd
  
read_file = pd.read_csv(r'table.csv')

read_file.to_excel(r'table.xlsx', index=True, header=True)
```

I want to convert csv to excel at python, and index=True with starting from 1, not 0 as default. I tried to read some pandas documentation about that, but I didn't find solution there.
Please help.

Comment: [start-index-at-1-for-pandas-dataframe/20168416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167930/start-index-at-1-for-pandas-dataframe/20168416) might help.